# Using OAuth for Google App Engine Endpoints from third party servers

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, access-token

I have a Google App Engine application deployed which contains and manages user data. My users may want to share their personal data with third party sites. Think Garmin sharing running data with myfitness pal or Strava.

The google documentation is gives good examples for using endpoints with iOS, Android, and javascript based web apps. These examples use a client id but not a "client secret" and do not involve refreshing the access tokens.

I have a javascript app running on a third-party site that does one time lookups against the api well.

I’d like to create a sample server app, preferably in java, that would connect periodically using an assigned client secret and refresh access tokens.

I have found documentation for accessing Google API's at the second link below but it is not clear if "Google APIs" include Google App Engine endpoints or just the standard suite of google apis.

What is not clear to me is that at the first link the documentation suggests that a client library needs to be generated from the backend endpoint api using maven or the endpoints.sh tool. Examples are provided for iOS/Android but there is no discussion for third party access.

Does anyone know is the server access configuration I describe possible with custom endpoints? Has anyone encountered example code for a server app that uses refresh tokens against an endpoint api?

Thanks!

End Points Documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

OAuth Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp